# What's the difference between a costant $k$ and $arity = 0$?

Tags: functions, logic, operator-theory

What kind of mathematical entities can have $arity = 0$ without being a constant ?

Or there is a concept that generalize the concept of constant and I can't see it ?

**Background**: I am having some troubles in grasping the real meaning of an *operator* when dealing with linear algebra and matrices; the so called identities like $0$ for algebraic sum and $1$ for the multiplication, can be seen as an operator? Which means that the identity matrix is an operator of arity $0$, which means that an identity matrix can be generalized as a matrix $M$, $n \times n$ wide where all cells are 0 except the ones at the coordinates $i,j$ where $i=j=n$? So the identity matrix operator is basically an infinite matrix?

Comment: Whether one calls them constant symbols or function symbols of arity $0$ makes no difference.

Comment: @AndréNicolas are you sure they are exactly 100% the same ? I having some troubles in grasping the real meaning of an _operator_ when dealing with linear algebra and matrices; the so called _identities_ like $0$ for algebraic sum and $1$ for the multiplication, can be seen as an operator ? Which means that the identity matrix is an operator of arity $0$, which means that an identity matrix can be generalized as a matrix $M, n \times n$ wide where all cells are 0 except the ones at the coordinates $i,j$ where $i=j=n$ ? So the identity matrix operator is basically an infinite matrix ?

Comment: with _infinite matrix_ I mean that an operator, in this case the identity matrix, defines a _"rule"_ that is applicable to an object of an indefinite size .

Comment: Yes, $100\%$ absolutely. The thing that changes is the interpretation, but that difference is present with constant symbols also.

Comment: @AndréNicolas so there is a difference, for example the concept of _identity matrix_ scales better than a constant $k$ for a matrix, $k$ is of definite size, an operator is not defined in size .

Comment: I think arity means different things in different (sub) fields of mathematics, In logic an "connective of arity 0" is a constant $\bot$ or $\top$ , but in other fields "arity" can have an other meanings,